# IKVMC unable to load runtime assembly

Tags: mono, ikvm

I have a very simple jar file and I'm trying to convert it to a mono dll using ikvmc, but I'm getting the message "Error: unable to load runtime assembly".

My command line is:

```
  ikvmc -target:library test.jar
```

My jar contains only one class, that simply has a method returning a String.

I'm just trying to experiment with ikvmc at this point before starting to develop some more complicated things.

I'm using:

Open Suse 11.3, 32 bits
kernel 3.11.6-4-desktop
ikvmc version 0.44.0.5
mono 3.0.6

Any hints?

Comment: share full error (including stack trace), full command line arguments, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got it working...

I've copied all files on folder "/usr/lib/mono/ikvm" to folder "/usr/lib/ikvm".

Apparently, ikvmc searches for runtime assemblies on the same folder where ikvmc executable are located.

If someone knows a workaround or a unkown (for me, at least) setting that avoids such copy, I really would like to know.